# How would I use a function to programmatically control which jquery-ui "accordion" panel should open?

Tags: jquery-ui

## QUESTION:

How would I use a function to programmatically control which jquery-ui "accordion" panel should open?

Thanks for any help/guidance!

***NOTE: Below, are some examples of what I've tried to open the accordion panel using a function are shown below.***

--Unfortunately, none of these work.

**(jquery 1.8.0,  jquery-ui  1.8.23)**

## 1.

```
    $('#abc').accordion(
    {
        active: false,
        icons: false,
        collapsible: true,
        animated: true,
        navigation: true,
        event: "click keyup",
        create: function(event, ui) {      
            $("#abc").accordion( "option" , "active" , getAindex() );
        }            
    });
```

## 2.

```
    $('#abc').accordion(
    {
        icons: false,
        active: function(event, ui) {   
            return getAindex();
        },
        collapsible: true,
        animated: true,
        navigation: true,
        event: "click keyup"
    });
```

## 3.

```
    $('#abc').accordion(
    {
        icons: false,
        active: getAindex(),
        collapsible: true,
        animated: true,
        navigation: true,
        event: "click keyup"
    });
```

## The "getAindex()" function looks like this...

```
    function getAindex()
    {
        var idx = 0;
        var jqXHR2 = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'getAindex',
            async: false,
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            idx = data
            $("#aindex").val(idx);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("FAIL:  getAindex: jqXHR:" + jqXHR + "...textStatus:" + textStatus + "...errorThrown:" + errorThrown");
        });

        return idx;
    }
```

## The HTML looks like this...

```
    <div id="abc">
        <h3>tabA</h3>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>tabA-content1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>tabA-content2</span>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <h3>tabB</h3>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>tabB-content1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>tabB-content2</span>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <h3>tabC</h3>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>tabC-content1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>tabC-content2</span>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

## The "fixed" accordion definition...

```
    $('#abc').accordion(
    {
        active: getAindex(),
        icons: false,
        collapsible: true,
        animated: true,
        navigation: true,
        event: "click keyup",
        change: function(event, ui) {              
            if (ui.options.active !== false)
            {
                setAindex(ui.options.active);
            }
        }          
    });
```

## The "fixed" Aindex() function...

```
    function getAindex()
    {
        var idx = 0;
        var jqXHR2 = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'getAindex',
            async: false,
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            idx = parseInt(data);    //  <== NOTE:  added this...
            $("#aindex").val(idx);   
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("getAindex() - FAIL:  jqXHR:" + jqXHR + "...textStatus:" + textStatus + "...errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
        });

        return idx
    }
```

Comment: Is `$('#abc')` your accordion wrapper div? Do you use an `<h`number `>` tag before your `<div>`s which is be your content panel? Please provide HTML code.

Comment: Hi PHPglue - Yes, the "$('#abc')" is the accordion wrapper. Also, yes - I use an "<h3>" before the panel content div.  I added a sample of what the HTML looks like, above.  Thanks for responding to my post!

Comment: Your first and third code snippets should work. Can you post the code of `getAindex()`? (Maybe it is asynchronous or does not return a number.)

Comment: What's `getAindex()`? Where's the code?

Comment: Thanks - I added the function that is called, above. I verified that it is at least returning the correct value.  I had tried adding the return value to 0, to see if it made a difference (i.e., force it to be a number... e.g.,  return (idx + 0)

Comment: @saim, that function is asynchronous. It cannot immediately return a meaningful value. You will have to rethink your design, and create the slider widget from the callback function you pass to `done()`.

Comment: Thank you Frederic.  Usually, (in my own experience, at least) these sorts of "unintuitive" issues end up being the result of a confluence of circumstances.  But, for now, I have taken your original simple advice into account (i.e., "or does not return a number"), and it seems to have "fixed" the problem (thank you). -I had arrogantly assumed I'd covered this possibility - but, I was wrong.   I will post the improved code above.  Thanks again for  your generous help!

Comment: Your `url: 'getAindex'`, inside your `function getAindex`. Is that really a url?

Comment: Yes.  'getAindex' points to a method in a controller class